# how to pass the string from django to javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I used to pass the variables in terms of dictionary to HTML template in Django without any problem. Now I plan to add some javascript into the HTML file, and use the same way "{{ }}" to obtain the object from dictionary in javascript. All the objects in the dictionary are actually strings.
In Django, the code is:

```
dataDict = {}
dataDict["time"] = json.dumps(",".join(timeList))
return render_to_response("xxxx.html", dataDict,\
         context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And in HTML page and Javscript, I just want use a string variable to receive it and then resolve the information I want, and our code is:

```
var test = {{ time }};
```

But it seems Django cannot pass the data to the string variable in Javascript. So I have two questions:

1. Is there some special type of variable to pass the data from the Django to Javascript. Does JSON be possible? Or is it a must to convert string to JSON string in Django first before passing to Javascript?
2. How to use the delivered string in Javascript? Apparently just use var xx = xxxx; doesn't work. We think we can pass data but it seems cannot be processed.

Does anybody have some idea about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you just need to double quote it?

`var test = "{{time}}";`

Let's assume that `dataDict['time'] = "1:30 PM, 2:30 PM"`.    When your template is rendered it creates this text (verify it yourself w/ view source):

```
var test = 1:30 PM, 2:30 PM;
```

As you can see, this isn't valid JavaScript.  When you double quote it it becomes this:

```
var test = "1:30 PM, 2:30 PM";
```

Similarly, you'll want to double quote your DOM elements with interpolated attributes, e.g., `<a href="{{url}}">..</a>`.   The Django [builtin template filter docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) have numerous examples of this.

It's important to keep in mind the difference between template evaluation / rendering time in your Python environment and JavaScript browser execution / evaluation time, especially when you try to pass data between the two.

Comment: Thanks. It works well. But could you tell me why it needs " ", because I think {{time}} just pass an object to the javascript, so what is meaning of a object with two "? Is it a string?

Comment: Done, I've added more detail to my initially sparse post.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to JSON is recommended in order to prevent things such as spurious `</script>`-containing strings from causing issues with JavaScript. Assigning should be enough, since JSON strings look like JavaScript literals.

Comment: And for simple assignments there is `escapejs` filter: `escapejs('<>') -> u'\\u003C\\u003E'`

Comment: @Tomasz: Sure, but `\u003C\u003E` still isn't valid JavaScript without the quotes.

Comment: I've done some testing and even converting to JSON isn't a safe way and is still vulnerable to XSS, best use the `json_script` template filter.